# Not getting app updates in play store when publishing new update

Tags: android, flutter, dart, console

I have published a flutter app in play console. And when I releases a new version the existing user not getting update app button in play store. They need to uninstall and install app to get new update.

Comment: have you change you version code and version name and higher than the last one

Comment: i am updating version in yaml file 1.0.2+3. Is it right ?

Comment: I am updating the version in yaml. this is last 1.0.2+1 whenever i releases new one i incrementing the +1 every time. Is it right ?

Comment: No, you have to increase number in the front, from 1.0.2 to 1.0.3 the number behind plus is just build number for developers to track internally. User will face build version instead